# Нужно сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопку input range value было 0, а при повторном клике value вернулось как и было

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте дорогие программисты.Пытаюсь делать аудиоплеер. Делаю кнопку мута и хочу чтобы при муте ползунок был на значении 0, а когда размутиваю, то ползунок должен вернуться в положение в котором он был до мута. Заранее спасибо!

```
volIcon.onclick = function(){
    if(player.muted){
        player.muted = false;
    }else{
        player.muted = true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const volIcon = document.querySelector(".volume-mute");
const range = document.querySelector(".range");

volIcon.onclick = ((previousVol = Number(range.value), isMuted = false) => function(e) {
  if (isMuted && range.value === "0") {
    [isMuted, range.value] = [false, previousVol];
  } else {
    [isMuted, previousVol, range.value] = [true, Number(range.value), 0];
  }
})();
```

```css
.volume-mute {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input class="range" type="range">
<div class="volume-mute"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!